# Should Relu be used in LSTM hidden layers if Targets contain negative values?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, time-series, lstm

I'm aware that Relu as an ouput layer will only produce non-negative values, **should Relu be used however in the hidden layers if targets contains Negative and Positive values** ? (A linear regression model for Time Series)

Simple LSTM Example:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(64, activation = "relu")) # or without Relu?
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(32, activation = "relu")) # or without Relu?
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

Additional info: Targets are daily pct Change so mostly distribution is centered around 0 with range -10 < targets < 10

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using Relu is not an error here, but this does not mean that an other activation function would not generate better results, i would still try in doubt other functions, like leaky Relu.

The reason on why the Relu function is not wrong has to do with the fact that when you reach the relu the input has been already elaborated by the layer, this means that there is not a loss of information, because the negative values have been already modified by the network.

The only thing to keep in mind is that if you use relu before the output you can't generate negative values for obvious reasons.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by: "if you use relu before the output you can't generate negative values for obvious reasons." , don't get what you mean by that? @ BestDogeStackoverflow

Comment: sorry, with "before the output" i intended as last layer, so use it as an output layer